# Java regex issues with an exact token

Tags: java, regex, string

In my Java app I have a "template string", say, "*This record's name is : %%%NAME%%%.*"

I want to loop through a list and for each iteration, print out a "customized version" of this template that string-replaces the `%%%NAME%%%` token for a meaningful value.  For instance:

```
List<String> strNamesList = getNamesSomehow();
String strTemplate = "This record's name is : %%%NAME%%%.";
String strCustomized = "";
for(int i = 0; i < strNamesList.size(); i++)
{
    strCustomized = strTemplate.replaceFirst(strSomeRegex, strNamesList.get(i));
    System.out.println(strCustomized);
}
```

Per usual, I am choking on the `strSomeRegex`. I simply need a regex that will match for the exact phrase:

`%%%NAME%%%`

I have Googled, Binged, Wikipediaed and more. Searches for "match regex on exact" (and their likes) turn back all sorts of things, none of which help me with this token that has punctuation (percentage signs) in it.

Regexes are just one of those things that get me every time, and this is my last resort.

Thanks to any kind StackOverflowers who can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the percent signs are your only issue, backslash is used to escape special characters in regex.

So your pattern should be `\%\%\%NAME\%\%\%`

Which means in Java, one would write:

```
String patternString = "\\%\\%\\%NAME\\%\\%\\%";
```

**EDIT:** Wait, but is `%` a regex special character? I assumed it was, but the following code worked for me:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%%%NAME%%%");
Matcher m = p.matcher("This record's name is : %%%NAME%%%.");
System.out.println(m.replaceFirst("Bob")); //prints "This record's name is : Bob."
```

I don't see `%` mentioned anywhere in the documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

java has a function to quote a string in a regex [`java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(string)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)

what this does is surround the string with `\Q` and `\E` (replacing `\E` with `\E\\E\Q` in the string as needed)

in your example `"\\Q%%%NAME%%%\\E"` will do